# React/Redux - dispatch store on window.resize

Tags: reactjs, resize, redux, addeventlistener, flux

I am working on a responsive website (React/Redux), which renders the page as soon as a specified Breakpoint is reached. Every time the Browser calls the resize-event, I am going to update the store.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    store.dispatch(screenResize(...));
});
```

Does anyone know the performance impact of the dispatch if its called several times per second.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this in CSS with media queries? That's generally a much simpler solution to this sort of problem.

Comment: I used media queries for the most elements. But some elements must change their logic if another Breakpoint is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Since presumably this is only going to get called when the page is actually being resized, it's probably not going to be too much of an issue.  That said, as a general observation, you may want to consider throttling the dispatch.

Also FYI, there's some existing libraries to help track window size in Redux.  See the [Use Cases#Page Interaction](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/use-cases.md#page-interaction) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links).

Comment: That's what I thought as well.. But I can not throttle the dispatch, because I must react immediately on the change. That is why I call the dispatch each time the event is called

Comment: Another option I've used before is in combination with [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) where you use the component's local state to track the immediate changes then once the user is completed the resize you persist the change to the store.